# HOW TO iMacro If Else Statement without Javascript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, eval, imacros, goto

I currently make a iMacro script that use EXTRACT to find the TAG

```
VERSION BUILD=9030808 RECORDER=FX
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
TAB T=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=I ATTR=CLASS:icon-pencil&&TXT: EXTRACT=HTM

SET !VAR10 EVAL("var s='{{!EXTRACT}}'; if(s=='<i class=\"icon-pencil\" style=\"outline: 1px solid blue;\"></i>'){s='imacros://run/?m=ADD.iim';} else {s='imacros://run/?m=A.iim';}; s;")
URL GOTO={{!VAR10}}
```

How can I make the if statement ?

Answer (score 0):

iMacros does not have if statements in it, from their FAQ:

> The iMacros language itself is designed as a descriptive language
>   (similar to HTML) and does not contain conditional statements. We did
>   not add such statements as we do not think that our customers should
>   have to attend week-long seminars just to learn yet another
>   proprietary scripting or programming language. In other words, iMacros
>   commands refer to web page elements, so any programming logic must be
>   put into a script that then uses iMacros to automate the website. -[iMacros FAQ](http://wiki.imacros.net/FAQ#Q:_Are_there_conditional_statements_like_if..._then...else_in_the_iMacros_macro_language.3F)

You can use Javascript however it is not that good to interface with, if you are looking into browser automation I would recommend [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) with Python. It is much easier to do anything that requires logic, iMacros is only useful for the very basic things.